# Como verificar se existe uma string nesse array?

Tags: php

Como eu posso verificar se existe a string "2017-11-15" nesse array?

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#43 (1) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-11-13"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#44 (1) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-11-14"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#45 (1) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-11-15"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#46 (1) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-11-16"
  }
}
```

Tentei assim e não consegui:

```
$string = "2017-11-15";
if(in_array($string, (array) $proposal_dates)){
        echo 'existe no array.';
    } else{
        echo 'nao existe no array';
    }
```

Comment: Não consegue armazenar uma string no lugar do objeto? assim fica mais simples de comparar.

Comment: você diz o retorno do array?

Comment: Isso, vc ta usando a classe `DateTime()`?

Comment: Esse array vem do banco, eu faço um select e me retorna todas as datas referente aquele ID. Não estou usando essa classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map()` para extrair o valor do objeto retornar um array com apenas o valor, depois pode comparar direto no `in_array()`

```
$plainArray = array_map(function($item){ return $item->date;} , $proposal_dates);

if(in_array($string, $plainArray)){
   echo 'existe no array.';
} else{
   echo 'nao existe no array';
}
```

Comment: Valeu rray, deu certo! Eu estava pensando em converter para json e verificar se existe essa string dentro do json

Answer (score 2):

Se não funcionou do jeito que vc fez (acredito que seja pq vc tem um objeto dentro do array) , vc pode tentar percorrer todo o array e ir verificando um a um assim :

```
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if($value->date == $string)
             echo 'existe no array.';
        } else{
              echo 'nao existe no array';
        }
    }
```